# Swap TLS and SSL tags?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

[The TLS tag is a synonym for the SSL tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ssl/synonyms). When people tag with [tls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tls) they get [ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssl). It's 2016 and SSL has been mostly beaten to death. I don't think the horse has any life left in it.

I think it would be a good idea to either:

1. split SSL and TLS since they are not really synonyms, or
2. make SSL a synonym of TLS since folks are advised to avoid SSL.

I kind of favor (1) because SSL and TLS are distinct families of protocols, but I'm not sure if it's feasible. The upcoming TLS 1.3 is a leap away from all of the SSL problems, and many downlevel TLS problems. There's even been talks on the IETF mailing list to call TLS 1.3 by the name TLS 2.0.

The second choice (2) is probably the next best thing. At minimum, it's not an offensive eye sore. It will also allow folks to tag with SSL when it actually applies to a problem, like user agents abandoning support for SSL due to its incumbent defects.

I'm not sure which tag best applies here... I'm tossing in [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) in case someone not familiar with the technologies wants to debate it.

---

Attempting to execute the *"Suggest Synonym"* process for SSL results in:

> Failed to propose synonym:
>
> The suggested tag must exist in the system before suggesting it as a
>   synonym!

But I'm not sure I'm using the process correctly. Or maybe it's an issue with circular synonyms.

Comment: SSL and TLS are different versions of the same thing (a family of protocol versions), additionally a lot of libraries still call it SSL (e.g. LibreSSL is not called LibreTLS).

Comment: [Crypto.SE also discussed this a while back and indeed switched to TLS](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/a/549/23623).

Answer (score 13):

In my view, TLS and SSL should still be synonyms, as even though they technically refer to different standards, in common usage they are often treated as interchangeable terms. [Even Wikipedia redirects "Secure Sockets Layer" to "Transport Layer Security"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer).

That said, I agree that SSL should be aliased to TLS, and not the other way around. TLS is the more modern standard, and often when people refer to SSL these days they really mean TLS.

For cases where people actually need to refer to a specific version of the standard, version-specific tags should be used. (E.g. [tls1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tls1.2))

Answer (score 6):

My position on the SSL vs TLS debate is expressed [here](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/549/28), on the Meta site for Crypto.SE. Basically, I use "SSL" to denote the complete family of protocols, of which "TLS" is only one part.

Now there is a widespread interpretation, that I often encounter in practical, professional situations, in which some people use "SSL" to designate SSL 2.0 and SSL 3.0, and "TLS" for TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2. This terminology corresponds to, let's say, the *branding* (the main reason why SSL was renamed TLS is because SSL was a trademark from Netscape and the IETF wanted an unencumbered name); however, if we look at the protocol details, the split should go between SSL 2.0 and SSL 3.0, not between SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0.

My interpretation of the names implies that SSL is the larger concept, and thus should be the canonical name. However, if it makes some people angry, doing it the other way round is not much of a problem, as long as the two tags are, effectively, synonyms, which is the most important point. The point of tagging is for narrowing search scopes, for the benefit of people who will ask questions or look for answers, and a lot of them don't know what TLS is (if they knew, they would ask less questions).

Comment: Its also worth noting that C, C++ and Objective C are a family of languages. But the C and C++ folks want to tar and feather people for using both tags. Even for question where it would be useful to know how the standards diverge ([unions and inactive member access](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11373203) comes to mind).